# Index Out of Range Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code. I am trying to get images uploaded to Firebase Storage and populate each of them on the coresponding cells. When I run the program I get Fatal Error: Index out of range on the line:

```
cell.adImageView.image = fotografiiProfil[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1]
```

Could you find a result why does this happen?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

class AnunturiViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    /*****************************************/

    var anunturi: [Produs] = [Produs]()

    var docRef: CollectionReference!
    var docRefNrTotalProduse: DocumentReference!

    let imageNames = ["sneakers", "tshirt", "hoodie", "jacket", "pants", "accessory"]

    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    var fotografiiProfil: [UIImage] = []

    var nrTotalProduse: Int = 0
    var isDone: Bool!

    // MARK: - Application Methods
    /*****************************************/

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        isDone = false

        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 49))

        docRefNrTotalProduse = Firestore.firestore().collection("anunturi").document("anunturi")

        reloadTableView()
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Delegate and DataSource Methods
    /*****************************************/

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ADCell") as! ADTableViewCell
        if isDone == true {
            print(indexPath.row)
            cell.adImageView.image = fotografiiProfil[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1]
            cell.numeLabel.text = self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].nume
            cell.descriereLabel.text = self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].descriere
            cell.marimeLabel.text = self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].marime
            cell.locatieLabel.text = self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].locatie
            cell.pretLabel.text = self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].pret
            switch self.anunturi[nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1].categorie {
            case "sneakers":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[0])
                break
            case "tricouri":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[1])
                break
            case "bluze":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[2])
                break
            case "jachete":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[3])
                break
            case "pantaloni":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[4])
                break
            case "accesorii":
                cell.categorieImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageNames[5])
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nrTotalProduse
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 164.0
    }

    // MARK: - IBACtions
    /*****************************************/

    @IBAction func onRefreshButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        reloadTableView()
    }

    // MARK: - Fetch Data From Firestore
    /*****************************************/

    func reloadTableView() {
        fetchDataForNumberOfProducts()
    }

    func fetchData() {
        anunturi.removeAll()
        docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("anunturi")
        docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    if document == querySnapshot?.documents.last {
                        self.fetchImages()
                    } else {
                        let produs = Produs(nume: (data["nume"] as? String)!,
                                            descriere: (data["descriere"] as? String)!,
                                            marime: (data["marime"] as? String)!,
                                            produsNou: (data["produsNou"] as? Bool)!,
                                            fotografii: (data["fotografii"] as? [String])!,
                                            locatie: (data["locatie"] as? String)!,
                                            livrezTara: (data["livrezTara"] as? Bool)!,
                                            email: (data["email"] as? String)!,
                                            telefon: (data["telefon"] as? String)!,
                                            pret: (data["pret"] as? String)!,
                                            autor: (data["autor"] as? String)!,
                                            categorie: (data["categorie"] as? String)!)
                        self.anunturi.append(produs)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchImages() {
        for i in 0...(nrTotalProduse - 1) {
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageRef = storage.reference()
            let imageRef = storageRef.child("fotografii/" + anunturi[i].fotografii[0])
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    self.fotografiiProfil.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                    if i == self.nrTotalProduse - 1 {
                        self.doneFetching()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func doneFetching() {
        isDone = true
        tableView.reloadData()
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func fetchDataForNumberOfProducts() {
        docRefNrTotalProduse = Firestore.firestore().collection("anunturi").document("anunturi")

        docRefNrTotalProduse.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error ?? "0") }
            else {
                let data = snapshot?.data()
                self.nrTotalProduse = data!["numarAnunturi"] as! Int
                self.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the confusion we've had trying to solve the error with your post, I decided to give you an example of a way I've done what you're doing (at least what I think you're doing). There is a bit of cleaning up that would make your code easier to understand and more efficient. Primarily, I'm not sure why you're doing math to calculate an array's index instead of using `indexPath.row`. That is exactly where your problem lies. This code will hopefully clear up how to get your data to share the same indices to avoid the calculation you were doing.

First I defined a class (like you did) to hold the data for what was stored in database. Here is that class:

```
class Angel {
    var name: String? 
    var email: [String]? // multiple Emails
    var phone: [String]? // multiple Numbers
    var photo: UIImage? // variable to hold image 
    var filepath: String? // variable to hold image URL 
}
```

Next I created a datasource singleton to share the data between all pages in my application. There is more to this dataSource but for the sake of this example this is what you need to see:

```
class PageDataSource {
    /**
     Store for Angel, User, CRUD, and Checkin info
     */

    var angels = [Angel]() // array to hold the Angel objects
    var crudIsAvailable: Bool? // check for connection stored variable

    // singleton for global access
    static let sharedInstance = PageDataSource()
    private init() {}
}
```

After the Angel object was stored to Firebase, I had to program a way to retrieve it:

```
// Read function to download the data from Firebase 
func readAngels(completion:  @escaping (_ error: NSError?) -> Void)  {
    if PageDataSource.sharedInstance.crudIsAvailable == true { // check for connection
        Database.database().reference().child("angels").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            var angels = [Angel]() // array to store firebase data 
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots { // loop through each angel object stored in the database
                    var angel = Angel()
                    if let dict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        angel.name = dict["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        angel.email = dict["email"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                        angel.phone = dict["phone"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                        angel.filepath = dict["photo"] as? String ?? "" // get filepath for photo download 

                        angels.append(angel) // add new angel to array 
                    }
                }
                PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels = angels // set new array of angels as the loaded angels in singleton
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion(NSError(domain: "Error reading Snapshots", code: 99, userInfo: nil))
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(NSError(domain: "Unavailable", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
    }
}
```

Calling the `readAngels()` function:

```
// using the readAngels() function to load angels
readAngels(completion: { (err) in
    if err != nil {
        print(err!.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        // do proper segue. No angels = sign up, 1 or more = login
        if PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels.count == 0 {
            // User exists but no angels have been stored
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            // Stored angels detected, proceed with app flow
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
})
```

After the `readAngels()` function has been called I would load the `tableView`. When the cells are laid out I read the data stored in the datasource and populate the cells. If there is a photo that has already been decoded in the datasource that is immediately loaded. If not I use the  `filepath` in the `datasource` to retrieve the image:

```
// tableView function to populate cells
// this will load images asyncronously as the cells are displayed on the screen
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellID") // set cell for reuse 
    // check for image already loaded in Datasource
    if let pic = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].photo  {
        // if image is already available set imageView content 
        cell.imageView?.image = pic
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        // if no image in Datasource pull it from firebase storage
    } else if let imgURL = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].filepath {
        Storage.storage().reference(forURL: imgURL).getData(maxSize: INT64_MAX, completion: { (data, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error downloading: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            // render
            let img = UIImage.init(data: data!)
            // store to datasource
            PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].photo = img
            // display  img
            if cell == tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imageView?.image = img
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Placeholder.png")
    }
    // set text
    cell.textLabel?.text = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.angels[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The index of `fotografiiProfil[]` cannot be below 0.

```
var num = indexPath.row -1
if nrTotalProduce = num && num < fotografiiProfil.count {
   cell.adImageView.image = fotografiiProfil[num]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, I get the same error, why I don't think? let's say nrTotalProduse is 5, that means that fotografiiProfil will be made out of 5 elements. and the last element of the array is fotografiiProfil[4]. fotografiiProfil[5 - 0 - 1] = 4.

Comment: That is correct that `5 - 0 - 1 = 4` but when the FIRST cell populates `indexPath.row` is 0. When you do this `indexPath.row - 1` you're making the `indexPath.row` equal to -1 which is out of bounds.

Comment: I understand what you want to say, but the instruction is called only when isDone = true so that means that nrTotalProduse will be greater than 0.

Comment: Yes, still index out of range

Comment: Sorry, You were right. I edited my answer to something that should correct your issue.

Comment: It still get the same error. This is the github repository, maybe you could see better: https://github.com/flaviusdolha/Hyype

Comment: I'll give you a new answer in a little bit.

Comment: Can you add an image of your data in Firebase? I want to see what is going on.

Comment: There is a lot to sift through in your code. I decided to provide a second answer that is some code that I've used in a project that I think is very similar to what you're trying to accomplish. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate your index :  `nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1`.
It can't be below 0 or beyond the last item of your array `fotografiiProfil` (length - 1).

Adding a print of the index value before actually assigning it will help you debug your code.

Add :

```
print(indexPath.row)
print(nrTotalProduse)
print(nrTotalProduse - indexPath.row - 1)
```

Comment: I get printed: 5 4 3 2 1 0, exactly what I want, I have 6 items.

Comment: are you sure it happens on this index then ?

Comment: That's my problem, I just get index out of range, but I am afraid it is caused by the fetchImages() function